# Uncommenting in Woocommerce template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

I don't have much experience with PHP and was wondering if anyone could help me uncomment a few lines from the Woocommerce thankyou.php template that can be found here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/thankyou.php . I need to remove the order details starting line 43-77:

```
    <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

        <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
            <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
        </li>

        <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
            <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
        </li>

        <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
            <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
        </li>

        <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>

        <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
            <?php _e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
        </li>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "uncomment"? There are no comments in your code.

Comment: i dont understand what the problem is. If you want to remove/comment a part of the template, you just can delete/comment the html from the original file (like you did already). Then you just have to place this file in path-to-your-theme-folder/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php and it will be effective (create folders if they don't exist)

Comment: Which things(portion) you want to remove from your template ? can you describe more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not clear. I think you want us to help you commenting a portion of code on that **`checkout/thankyou.php`** template, to remove some info from line 43 to 77…

So your template code will be:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>

<div class="woocommerce-order">

    <?php if ( $order ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

        <?php endif; /* else: ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                    <?php _e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php endif; */ ?>

            </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I hope that is simply that…

---

Official Documentation: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding templates in WooCommerce is quite simple, you just have to copy the template file you want to edit into the `YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/` directory and edit/add/delete anything you want.

In your case you just have to copy the template file located in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php` into `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/checkout` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you override the template files in child theme, otherwise after updating theme you will lose you changes.

Child theme creation procedure:

- create a folder in themes directory and name it yourthemename-child
- creat a style.css file and put this comment inside it 
  /*
    Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
    Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
    Template:     parent_theme_name
    you can add other attributes here as well
  */